# XML parsing for inner most child node in php

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I'm working parsing an XML file, can anyone help me to parse the last and innermost child node.

```
<section index="2.2.4" title="Recommendation" ref="RECOMMENDATION">
          <text>DWS strongly recommends that all authentication credentials should be configured with a strong password.</text>
          <text>DWS recommends that:</text>
          <list type="bullet">
            <listitem>passwords should be at least eight characters in length;</listitem>
            <listitem>characters in the password should not be repeated more than five times;</listitem>
            <listitem>passwords should include both upper case and lower case characters;</listitem>
            <listitem>passwords should include numbers;</listitem>
            <listitem>passwords should include punctuation characters;</listitem>
            <listitem>passwords should not include the username;</listitem>
            <listitem>passwords should not include a device's name, make or model;</listitem>
            <listitem>passwords should not be based on dictionary words.</listitem>
          </list>
          <text>Notes for Cisco Catalyst Switch devices:</text>
          <text>The following commands can be used on Cisco Catalyst Switch devices to set the enable password, create a local user with a password and to delete a local user:<code><command>enable secret <cmduser>password</cmduser></command>
<command>username <cmduser>user</cmduser> secret <cmduser>password</cmduser></command>
<command>no username <cmduser>user</cmduser></command>
</code></text>
        </section>
```

can anyone help to parse this innermost child node in PHP?

```
 <code><command>enable secret <cmduser>password</cmduser></command>
    <command>username <cmduser>user</cmduser> secret <cmduser>password</cmduser></command>
    <command>no username <cmduser>user</cmduser></command>
    </code></text>
            </section>
```

Especially this command cmd user command???

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Which data are you finding it difficult to process?

Comment: There's libraries existing for that purpose. If you really want to do it yourself, use recursivity

Comment: i need to parse the  <code><command>enable secret <cmduser>password</cmduser></command>
    <command>username <cmduser>user</cmduser> secret <cmduser>password</cmduser></command>
    <command>no username <cmduser>user</cmduser></command>
    </code></text>
            </section> especially i need the output, but im unable to parse it , i get data till The following commands can be used on Cisco Catalyst Switch devices to set the enable password, create a local user with a password and to delete a local user:     after that its not coming??? can please provide any code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php?rq=1

Comment: I tired recursive method, but I want to parse out the data from this <test><code><cmduser><command></test> , please provide a sudo code if possible ??

Comment: Can somebody post a pseudo code for this parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on which part of the data you want, you can load it into SimpleXML and then use XPath to search for the `<code>` element, so a basic version would be...

```
$fileName = "out.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($fileName);

$code = $xml->xpath("//code");
echo "command=".trim($code[0]->command).PHP_EOL;
echo "cmduser=".trim($code[0]->command->cmduser).PHP_EOL;
echo "cmduser=".trim($code[0]->command[1]->cmduser[0]).PHP_EOL;
```

would give you (with the test data)...

```
command=enable secret
cmduser=password
cmduser=user
```

Or if you want to pick the `<command>` element with both the user and password, you can use XPath to select the element with 2 `<cmduser>` elements...

```
$code = $xml->xpath("//code/command[count(cmduser)=2]");
echo "cmduser1=".trim($code[0]->cmduser[0]).PHP_EOL;
echo "cmduser2=".trim($code[0]->cmduser[1]).PHP_EOL;
```

Which give

```
cmduser1=user
cmduser2=password
```

Comment: Thank you Nigel Ren